# Checking equality of an element in Array - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, equals

For checking equality in a simple array, i've the following;

```
int a[4] = {9,10,11,20};
    if(a[3]== 20){
        cout <<"yes"<< endl;
    }
```

However, when I create an array of type class, and try and check equality I get error;

> Human is a class with private variables for name, age, gender etc, and
>   get and set functions for these variables.
>
> humanArray has size 20

```
void Animal::allocate(Human h){
    for (int i =0; i<20; i++){
        if(humanArray[i] == h){
            for(int j = i; j<size; j++){
                humanArray[j] = humanArray[j +1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get following error;

```
error: no match for 'operator==' in '((Animal*)this)->Animal::humanArray[i] == h'|
```

I could pass in the index and Human, and check against index number. However, is there a way to check if two elements are same? I don't wish to check say 'Human name' against human name, since for some parts my human will not have a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make the syntax

```
if(humanArray[i] == h)
```

legal, you will need to define `operator==` for your human class.  To do this, you might write a function that looks like this:

```
bool operator== (const Human& lhs, const Human& rhs) {
   /* ... */
}
```

Inside this function, you would do a field-by-field comparison of `lhs` and `rhs` to see if they were equal.  From this point forward, any time that you try to compare any two humans by using the `==` operator, C++ will automatically call this function for you to make the comparison.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the `operator==` for the class Human

```
bool operator== (const Human& left, const Human& right)
{
// perform comparison by each element in the class Human
}
```